# Set --no-optional parameter globally for all packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

Is it possible to set the `--no-optional` parameter globally, so every time I run `npm install XYPackage` it installs this package without optional dependencies? In my projects I have a `npm install` scripts with this parameter, but the problem is, when I want to install a new package, I always forgot to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply type on terminal:

```
$ npm set optional false
```

The previous command set your user configuration for npm (~/.npmrc on Linux). Then you can type "npm install" wherever you want and optional dependencies will not be installed. More info on npm config [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)

Comment: Not possible anymore.

npm ERR! The `optional` option is deprecated, and can not be set in this way
npm ERR!     Use `--omit=optional` to exclude optional dependencies, or
npm ERR!     `--include=optional` to include them.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     Default value does install optional deps unless otherwise omitted.